# How to write down the scenario outline example in cucumber, when you want to skip any column value and that column is mandatory for other test

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One |  | Three |
|  | Two | Three |

for Col2, the value is not there to compare in "Than", so need to skip. But this column is having value to compare for other test.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your use case , but you can use null as a value for that column .